# Plsql , same id entered in database after 24 hours

Tags: plsql

I want to retrive data in between 24 hours in plsql...
Ex. A vendorid came on 15.jan.2016, i have to check that how many times he will come again in company.

Comment: Please add proper description, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: I need to check how many ti mes an id cmes to data base in between 24 hours. I have invoice_date.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you require goes something like this:

```
   select vendorid, invoice_date ,count(*) from yourtable group by vendorid, invoice_date
```